# JavaScript - Validate dropdown using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to validate a dropdown using Vue.Js. This is the dropdown

```
<select name="notificationPreference" id="notificationPreference" v-model="notificationPreference">
    <option value hidden></option>
    <option value="1">Email</option>
    <option value="2">Text Message</option>
    <option value="3">Email and Text</option>
</select> </td> </tr>
```

I can already do this using just Javascript, like so

```
var e = document.getElementById("notificationPreference");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if(strUser==0)
{
    alert("Please select a service");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

However, I don't know how to do this with Vue.js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the model associated to the SELECT element is `notificationPreference`, you need to evaluate the model variable:

```
if (!this.notificationPreference){ // is null or zero
  alert("Please select a service");
}
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html for more information

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with watch:
Hope this helps.

```
<div id="app">
    <select name="notificationPreference"  v-model="notificationPreference">
        <option value hidden></option>
        <option value="1">Email</option>
        <option value="2">Text Message</option>
        <option value="3">Email and Text</option>
    </select> </td> </tr>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
   data:{
       notificationPreference:''
   },
   watch:{
       notificationPreference:  function (val) {
           if(val == 0){
                alert("Please select a service");
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
           }
       }
   }
});
```